# Why doesn't my Ionic project load at the server address?

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I have a project in IONIC. When i build my project (F5), the address (http://localhost:8100/) cannot show application.

My file: launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
]
```

Comment: did you try on http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: yes, only run using cmd with command ionic serve. Using VS Code dont run.

Comment: 8100 with VS Code, 8080 with CMD.

Comment: It's because you put http://localhost:8080 on your configurations, try to put http://localhost:8100 no  ?